# SSAS Cube load job get stuck, 32 GB RAM is fully used

Tags: sql-server

System:
Microsoft BI System with MSSql Server 2008 10.50.1600.1 with SSAS, SSIS and SSRS
on
virtual VM Server Windows Server 2008 Standard x64 with 32 GB RAM

Hello,

our BI System gets sometimes stuck in one Cube load job step.
The SSIS log shows the last Step, that was executed, but no error Message.
The job keeps running, but doesn't finish until i stop and start the last step again.
The Memory is fully used during the job and it is not the same step every time, sometime it's step 7/9 or sometimes step 8/9.

Our local support said, that we should raise the RAM on the System.
But we have a similar BI Testsystem, where almost the same load job is running with only 25 GB RAM and it finished every time. It's a few hours slower, but it finishes.

Besides:
We have Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter licences, but i can't switch the licence because we have no "Server 2008 Standard R2" System only a "Server 2008 Standard"

What can i try next? Do you need more Info? Thanks for your Help :)

best regards
Viktor